# What's this style of pictures called?

Tags: vintage

[image]

This kind of photography, I know you must get really high professional questions but just check on this. This pic is not old. It's clicked last year. And I liked how old and smooth this picture looks with a 80s touch and want to click some of these myself. Do you know how I can? Or if this really a trend, what's it called? Please reply on my email  [image]

Comment: Please read [Important information for asking "What's this effect?" questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/) and edit this post accordingly. Make sure to use a descriptive title, too. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the style of photography employed by Ka Xiaoxi?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/69758/what-is-the-style-of-photography-employed-by-ka-xiaoxi)

Answer (score 3):

It's called crappy on camera flash photography. But seriously folks, it is not a "STYLE" of Photography it is just not very good photography. Even when on camera flash is exposed properly (which this is not ) it is still not very flattering.  Conventional critiquing  and judgment aside  if you want to do this you will need a camera with a built-in flash  or a hotshoe you you can mount  a flash on to.   You will need to learn to balance the power of the flash with the ambient light  in order to achieve a good balance.  Adjust your flash compensation to -1  and experiment up or down from that setting. But a properly exposed photo may not be what you are after, so feel free to break the rules.

Comment: can I click these with a phone camera

Comment: @SadisticBloke What is it about these photos that you want to emulate with your phone camera?

Answer (score 0):

As **Alaska man** said, it's not a specific "style". That person used old (film) camera. It COULD BE Polaroid! But I'm sure it's film camera with flash.

I'm personally taking photos on Kiev-60 TTL with Kodak films. To make same photos - use **Polaroid** OR **electronic film camera** with flash.

It's impossible to do same shots with phone, because "result" is different. Photos made on phone are more "sharp" than photos made by film camera.

P.S. Buy film camera and you will have a really unforgettable feeling of taking shoot with it. Search on ebay some cams) And check if you have service where your photos can be developed