# How do I make my photos look like analog?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, photoshop, vintage

I'm in the middle of editing one of my projects. Unfortunately there are some photos that I would really love to edit to look like these ones but I can't figure out how to do that. Is there anybody  who would help me with it? I've tried to desaturate and sharpen them, I've tried tu use color filters but none of these helped. Any tricks? (I edit in PS and LR)

Thanks a lot for your help!

[image: credits: Lousy Auber][image: credits: Lousy Auber]

credits: Lousy Auber

Comment: "look like analog"  doesn't mean anything.  Please explain exactly what it is you find undesirable about your photo - and post it as well as the "desired" images you posted.

Comment: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to I edit a photo to have a old vintage look?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39546/how-to-i-edit-a-photo-to-have-a-old-vintage-look)

Comment: DxO Optics "Film Pack" software is available (for $) for people who wish to apply Professional versions of Instagram distortions to their images.

Comment: I don't think the two photos you have posted have the same or even a similar look. The one on the bottom is a lot warmer: compare the faces. And it introduces some greenish tones that are not present in the upper one.

Answer (score 1):

Applying an s-shaped tonal curve would be a good starting point. If that does not give you the expected look, there are plugins for photo editors that simulate films.

Comment: Do you mean an S-shaped tonal curve of RGB or of each color (R, G, B, RGB)? I've tried it, but still not the same look :(

Answer (score 1):

all depends what kind of analog film you would like to achieve.

after applying s-shaped tonal curve (contrast/highlights/shadows can be main issue). than you should play with temperature. and some grain can be nice (like high iso film). and playing with hue and each color channel can give you a better emulation.

it would be great to play with highlight and shadow tones. creamy highlights, red casting in shadows etc.

on internet there are lots of film emulation plug-ins. i think most famous is vsco filters.