# How can this retro effect be achieved in Lightroom?

Tags: post-processing, effect

I recently came across [this selection](http://www.behance.net/gallery/LMC2012/4519791?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20behance/vorr%20%28Behance%20Network%20Featured%20Projects%29&utm_content=Netvibes) of superb photos, all with a great retro effect. How can I achieve this effect in Lightroom?

Comment: Does this link still go to the original selection you intended? Can you describe the effect you're looking for, for future reference?

Comment: Yes, it does still link to the original selection.

Answer (score 7):

In general: warm up the white balance, massively reduce contrast, reduce colour saturation. Don't forget to shoot absolutely everything with a fast prime, wide open...

In this particular set a lot of fill light and or clarity has been used in some of the images to enhance textures, not strictly necessary and a little bit over done in my opinion.

see also [How do I get a "Film" look with a digital camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34945/how-do-i-get-a-film-look-with-a-digital-camera)

Comment: I lol'd at this one "Don't forget to shoot absolutely everything with a fast prime, wide open..."

Answer (score 3):

Lower contrast, lower saturation, slight yellow tint to the color balance, darken the white point and brighten the black point so that you don't have strong whites or blacks.  If necessary, add some noise or grain.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others already told you add a radial filter (since LR5) and reduce the clarity and the sharpness. You might have to repeat this multiple times depending how strong you want the effect to be.

Then add a post-crop vignetting. You could also do this by reducing the exposure with the radial filter, however I prefer to do this in a separate step using the vignetting setting.